# How to stop two finger touches on Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, panresponder

i had used this library for the draggable view for items
`react-native-draggable-gridview`
in that library i don't know how to stop two finger touches on the screen ,
i tried so many stuff but i didn't succeed.

here is the my code for gridView :-

```
<GridView
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.dragContainer}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          data={dragdata}
          numColumns={2}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          onReleaseCell={onReleaseCell}
          disableIntervalMomentum={true}
        />
```

below i shred the errors of the code when user touch the screen with two finger.

[image]